# Vertexbuffer Getdata VertexPositionNormalTexture

Tags: xna-4.0

I have a Vertexbuffer with 648 VertexPositionNormalTexture elements. That is 27 cubes and each cube hold 24 vertices.

If I want to access the vertices for my first cube I can write:

```
int startIndex = 0;

VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[24];

vertexBuffer.GetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(vertices, startIndex, 24);
```

The problem is if I want to access my 9th cube (24*9 = 216). I have to write:

```
int startIndex = 216;

VertexPositionNormalTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[startIndex + 24];

vertexBuffer.GetData<VertexPositionNormalTexture>(vertices, startIndex, 24);
```

I have to create 192 extra slots just to access my 24 elements. Because the vertex.GetData will copy to same index it get data from. How do I do so It write my 24 elements to a correct sized array?

All classes, structs and functions are from XNA Framework 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you need to use GetData?

Save the reference to your array and work with the array... not with the vertexBuffer...

Comment: I didn't save my array because I found it waste to save same data twice. So if I would need data I could just take it from the vertexbuffer. Is that bad?

Comment: retrieving vertex from gpu memory is not usual, if you need to modify your vertex keep them in main memory... is much better than using getdata because this way it does not generate garbage and it has much better perfomance...